# How does symmetry follow from the following expression (integral calculus)?

Tags: calculus, integration, symmetry

Hello mathematicians,

I cannot find the symmetry in the following expression (see image):

$$\int _{-3}^3(x^3 - 7x +2) \sqrt{9 - x^2}\, dx$$

How does the first component collapse (due to symmetry, I must suppose)? I do not see it. Any tips are much appreciated.

[image: Integral]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we note that $$\int _{-3}^3(x^3 - 7x +2) \sqrt{9 - x^2}\, dx = \int _{-3}^3 (x^3-7x)\sqrt{9-x^2}\,dx + \int_{-3}^{3}2\sqrt{9-x^2}\,dx.$$  Furthermore, if we consider $$f(x) = (x^3-7x)\sqrt{9-x^2}$$ then we can observe that
\begin{align*}
f(-x) &= ((-x)^3-7(-x))\sqrt{9-(-x)^2}\\&= (-x^3+7x)\sqrt{9-x^2}\\&= -(x^3-7x)\sqrt{9-x^2}\\&= -f(x)
\end{align*}
Since then we have $f(-x) = -f(x)$, we can conclude that $\int_{-3}^{3}f(x)\,dx = 0$, and so we have that $$\int _{-3}^3(x^3 - 7x +2) \sqrt{9 - x^2}\, dx = \int_{-3}^{3}2\sqrt{9-x^2}\,dx.$$

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant. Thank you so much. I am not adept at recognizing the possibility to split the +2 from (x^3-7x), this helps me quite a lot.